# Rest Console testing REST API needing a list of INT as parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, rest

I need to test a REST API, for an action that needs a list of int

I don't know what do with the parameters.

I've added this in the request payload

```
idAttachedFiles : 1007, 1008, 1009
```

But my list received is empty.
If I only add 1 ID, I get 1 value in the list

edit :
I've added a screenshot of my debugger receiving the POST from the rest console
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeeded that way :

inside the request payload, under "sKey", i added the followings :

```
idAttachedFiles[0]  |   1245
idAttachedFiles[1]  |   2345
```

And it finally worked

Answer (score 1):

is it GET or POST? 
for GET to make it a list you need `p[]=1&p[]=2`

for POST you should have payload as

```
{
ids:[1,2,3]
}
```

Comment: I should have said that your answer is something I had already tried. I've edited my answer with a screenshot of my Rest Console + my debugger

Comment: Your json payload is an object holding list of integers, not the list itself.You can use custom json and enable unwrapping, if you want to use directly the list.

Answer (score 1):

have you set the correct content type? its deselected by default and needs to be set to application/json in your case.